# No connection option for GitHub in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, github, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to use Git and save to GitHub in Visual Studio 2019. I can't find the option to connect to GitHub under Team Explorer/Manage connections. All I see is Azure DevOps. I added the GitHub extension for Visual Studio in the Visual Studio Installation program. I also created an account and a repository on GitHub.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you must install this extension:
[image]

after that, click on add to source control and select git:

[image]

and after that click on Publish to GitHub:
[image]

if this doesn't work install git on your windows:
https://git-scm.com/downloads
and try to repeat these steps.

Comment: I ran a repair on Visual Studio and that fixed it. Thanks!